# pyspark group by showing null value as 2 for sum aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

pyspark group by showing null value as 2 for sum aggregation

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, FloatType

sch=StructType([StructField('x', StringType()),
                StructField('y', IntegerType()),
                StructField('z', FloatType()),
                StructField('m', IntegerType()),
            ])
df1=spark.createDataFrame([('abbaba', 1, 2.0, 3), ('b', None, 3.0, 5), ('a', 1, None, None), (None, 2, 5.0, 3), ('a', 1, 2.0, 2), \
                           ('a', 1, 2.0, 2)], schema=sch)
df1.groupby(['x']).agg({'y':'sum'}).show()
```

```
+------+------+
|     x|sum(y)|
+------+------+
|abbaba|     1|
|     b|  null|
|  null|     2|
|     a|     3|
+------+------+
```

Comment: in your input's 4th row, x is None (null) and y is 2. so, a sum provided 2.